# Speeding up a Postgres query on millions of rows?

Tags: performance, postgresql

I am using Postgres 9.4. I have a large table. This is the structure of my table:

```
 processing_date | date                 |
 practice_id     | character varying(6) |
 chemical_id     | character varying(9) |
 items           | bigint               |
 cost            | double precision     |
Indexes:
    "vw_idx_chem_by_practice_chem_id" btree (chemical_id)
    "vw_idx_chem_by_practice_chem_id_vc" btree (chemical_id varchar_pattern_ops)
    "vw_idx_chem_by_practice_joint_id" btree (practice_id, chemical_id)
```

Now I want to run a LIKE query on the table. This is my query:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYSE, BUFFERS) SELECT sum(pr.cost) as actual_cost, 
      sum(pr.items) as items, pr.practice_id as row_id, 
      pc.name as row_name, pr.processing_date as date 
FROM vw_chemical_summary_by_practice pr 
JOIN frontend_practice pc ON pr.practice_id=pc.code 
WHERE (pr.chemical_id LIKE '0401%' ) 
GROUP BY pr.practice_id, pc.code, date 
ORDER BY date, pr.practice_id;
```

And this is the result of an EXPLAIN: http://explain.depesz.com/s/lYRT

As you can see, it's slow partly because it's running a bitmap heap scan on nearly 4 million rows. (The subsequent sort is also slow.)

Is there anything I can do to speed this up?

I'm wondering if I should create a further materialized view, or whether a multicolumn index would help, so that Postgres can look in the index rather than disk.

Is there some way I can also make the sort more efficient?

UPDATE: Here's the definition of the materialized view:

```
    CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW vw_chemical_summary_by_practice
    AS SELECT processing_date, practice_id, chemical_id, 
    SUM(total_items) AS items, SUM(actual_cost) AS cost
    FROM frontend_prescription
    GROUP BY processing_date, practice_id, chemical_id
```

And the underlying table:

```
id                | integer                 | not null default nextval('frontend_prescription_id_seq'::regclass)
 presentation_code | character varying(15)   | not null
 total_items       | integer                 | not null
 actual_cost       | double precision        | not null
 processing_date   | date                    | not null
 practice_id       | character varying(6)    | not null
Indexes:
    "frontend_prescription_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "frontend_prescription_528f368c" btree (processing_date)
    "frontend_prescription_6ea07fe3" btree (practice_id)
    "frontend_prescription_idx_code" btree (presentation_code varchar_pattern_ops)
    "frontend_prescription_idx_date_and_code" btree (processing_date, presentation_code)
```

UPDATE 2: In case it wasn't clear, I need to get total spending and items by practice and by month, across all chemical_ids that start with `0401.

Comment: create index idx_test on vw_chemical_summary_by_practice( substr( practice_id :: text from 1 to 4));

Then do substr( practice_id :: text from 1 to 4) = '0401'

If your practice_id contains values that are hierarchical, then it is still better to create an index of the first few characters of its values. Much smaller index.

Comment: Can you add the view definition ?

Comment: @Horia added, thanks

Comment: @nagylzs will that help? I think it's the looking up the values in 4 million rows that is slow, not the index query.

Comment: Is there any reason to put a numerical value in a text field? `WHERE (pr.chemical_id >= '0401'  AND pr.chemical_id < '0402'  ) ` will probably help, in the text case

Comment: Okay, I see now. He is actually making a query that retrieves millions of rows. In that case, he should cluster the table by practice_id or something similar.

Comment: @joop it does sometimes have text characters in too, though only in positions 8-9 of the string, if that helps.

Comment: @nagylzs I guess clustering would speed up sorting(?) but not the actual retrieval. Is that correct?

Comment: So it turns out to be a data-modelling issue after all.

Comment: I think it would do both, because retrieval is much faster when the wanted rows are collected on a few pages. By the way, did you ever create an index on the materialized view?

Comment: You can try first creating an INDEX on MATERIALIZED VIEW on chemical_id column to see if it helps on the HEAP SCAN

Comment: BTW what is the cardinality of chemical_id? (and practice_id; now we're at it)

Comment: @nagylzs and @Horia - there are already indexes on the matview's `chemical_id` column, see the definition at the top of the question. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: @joop - there are about 2500 chemical_ids and 10000 practice_ids.

Comment: Which I expected. So it is effectively an N:M junction table, relating 2500 chemicals to 10000 practices. I would squeeze them out into their respective "domain" tables, and refer to them by means of a surrogate id.

Comment: @joop - thank you! I don't know if I completely understand what you mean, could you possibly expand or add a link? I need to support queries for `practice_id=N`, `chemical_id=N`  and also for `chemical LIKE XX` where XX can be 2, 4 or 6 characters.

Answer (score 3):

```
-- assuming this is your original table:
CREATE TABLE practice_chemical_old
    ( processing_date date NOT NULL
    , practice_id     character varying(6) NOT NULL
    , chemical_id     character varying(9) NOT NULL
    , items           bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL
    , cost            double precision
    );

-- create these three new tables to decompose it into
CREATE TABLE practice
    ( practice_id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , practice_name character varying(6) UNIQUE
    );
CREATE TABLE chemical
    ( chemical_id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , chemical_name character varying(9) UNIQUE
    );

CREATE TABLE practice_chemical_new
    ( practice_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES practice (practice_id)
    , chemical_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES chemical (chemical_id)
    , processing_date date NOT NULL
    , items bigint NOT NULL default 0
    , cost double precision
            -- Not sure if processing_date should be part of the key, too
    , PRIMARY KEY (practice_id, chemical_id)
    );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON practice_chemical_new(chemical_id, practice_id);

INSERT INTO practice(practice_name)
SELECT DISTINCT practice_id FROM practice_chemical_old;

INSERT INTO chemical(chemical_name)
SELECT DISTINCT chemical_id FROM practice_chemical_old;

-- now populate the new tables from the old ones ...
INSERT INTO practice_chemical_new(practice_id, chemical_id, processing_date,items,cost)
SELECT p.practice_id, c.chemical_id, pco.processing_date, pco.items, pco.cost
FROM practice_chemical_old pco
JOIN practice p ON p.practice_name = pco.practice_id
JOIN chemical c ON c.chemical_name = pco.chemical_id
    ;

-- Now,  the original table *could* be represented by the following view (or table, or table expression):
CREATE VIEW practice_chemical_fake AS
SELECT pcn.processing_date AS processing_date
    , p.practice_name AS practice_id
    , c.chemical_name AS chemical_id
    , pcn.items AS items
    , pcn.cost AS cost
FROM practice_chemical_new pcn
JOIN practice p ON p.practice_id = pcn.practice_id
JOIN chemical c ON c.chemical_id = pcn.chemical_id
    ;
```

Note: it is not clear from the original question if multiple instances of {practice,chemical} are possible (with different processing_date). You could need to change the definition of the PK a bit.

Comment: yes, multiple instances of {practice, chemical} with different dates are possible.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not totally sure why it helps. The query is still to get any rows where the `chemical_id` starts `0401`. There are still 4 million entries where this is the case. So wouldn't it just mean that we'd run a 4-million-row query on the new table, not the old table? which would presumably be just as slow?

Comment: No, there are only 2500 chemicals to search. With the integer id and the indexed FK, the join is actually cheap. Plus: the memory and disk footprint (number of pages) is smaller. BTW: why don't you try? it is easy to keep the old & new versions in parallel.

Comment: I will try it. What query would I run on the above to get total spending, by practice and by month, for chemicals starting `0401`? I'm thinking it's `SELECT * FROM practice_chemical_new where chemical_id LIKE '0401%'` - wouldn't that have to search as many rows as before?

Comment: That's why I created the _fake view, emulating the _old table. And it is not about *rows*,  but about (disk) *pages*.

Comment: Also try cluster table practice_chemical_new on practice_chemical_new

@joop is the best, took the time to write all this code! :-)

Comment: @nagylzs Clustering *might* work, yes. But there is also the problem of processing_date being a potential key element (plus: maybe another , yet invisible, key component, leading to potential 4NF violations). Summarising: don't model your data to *speed up* one possible query; model it to support any *reasonable* query. In most cases this will be the most *compact* model, with the least amount of redundancy.

Comment: @joop - sorry silly question, but I guess I need to write one additional statement to import everything from `practice_chemical_old` into `practice_chemical_new`?

Comment: @joop would it be better to use a matview rather than a new table?

Comment: no, that is the part below `-- now populate the new tables from the old ones ...` wrt matview: how much will it cost to (re)synchronise the matview?